# How Do I Return IList<T> From ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, generics, collections, task-parallel-library

I have the following method:

```
    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        if(user.Roles == null)
        {
            // TODO: Load roles
        }

            //Not sure return syntax to return user.Roles as IList<string>
            return Task.FromResult<List<string>>(???);
    }
```

Where `user.Roles` are of type `ICollection<IAppRole>`the method above returns type of `IList<string>`. I'm having trouble making the conversion and then finding the proper syntax to make the return.

Comment: How do you expect `IAppUser` to turn into a `string`?

Comment: That was an error in my question, I just corrected, IAppUser should have been IAppRole, that method will take a collection of roles and return them as a list of string values (just the name) This is an Identity 2 UserStore custom store implementation.

Comment: So why not return `List<IAppRole>` instead?

Comment: The return must be of `IList<string>` as this is an implementation of the interface `IUserRoleStore<AppUser, int>` used in Identity 2, the UserStore.

Comment: Would appreciate a comment as to why the down vote? As you can see from my current reputation, I don't participate often, however, would like to start and of course contribute both meaningful questions and answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cast list of roles to list of strings:

```
user.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToList();
```

To return a task:

```
return Task.FromResult(user.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToList());
```